# How to hold floating topbar when scrolling down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

hi all i want to have a floating topbar on the top of my page and be visiable even if i scroll down the page. I tried to achieve this using following code but for some reason it doesn't work! After trying to troubleshoot i noticed that **$(document).ready(function()**
 never becomes true! could you guys help me what is wrong here ?

floating topbar:

```
<div class="FlyingTopBar">
    <div class="GlobalNav">    
      <div class="Content">
        <span class="Line"></span>

        <a class="Active" href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a  href="/link1.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a  href="/link2.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a  href="/link3.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a  href="/link4.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>



        <a  href="/link5.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a  href="/link6.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>

        <a  href="/link7.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>




        <a  href="/link8.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a href="/link9.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <a href="/link10.html" title="Link">Link</a>
        <span class="Line"></span>
        <div class="BottomFix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

javascript to hold the floating tobar on the top while scrolling down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/


   alert('start');

      var $flying_bar = $('div.FlyingTopBar');
      var amount_scrolled;
      var initial_top_position =0;
      var actual_top_position;

         $(document).ready(function() {
        updateCurrentPosition();
        alert('visable topbar1');
        $flying_bar.css('visibility','visible');
         alert('visable topbar2');

        $(window).bind('scroll', updateCurrentPosition);
        })

      function updateCurrentPosition() {
        amount_scrolled = $window.scrollTop();
        if (amount_scrolled < 0) amount_scrolled = 0;  //not tested iPad reversed scroll fix
        if (amount_scrolled < initial_top_position) {
          actual_top_position = initial_top_position - amount_scrolled;
          $flying_bar.css({'top':actual_top_position + 'px'});
        } else {
          $flying_bar.css({'top':'0px'});
        }
      }



    headerTickerInit('div.ReportTitleTicker');

    if( $('#ScrollPollSection').length > 0 ) {
      $('#SideNavPolls').show(0);
    }
  /*]]>*/
  </script>
```

part of css:

```
.FlyingTopBar {z-index:20; position:fixed; top:120px; left:0px; width:100%; visibility:hidden;} /* <- top updated by JS */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to FlyingTopBar class, there is really no need of using JavaScript in such cases :-

```
. FlyingTopBar { position : fixed; top: 0px; width:100%; z-index:20; }
```

To read more about fixed positioning, go through : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

I hope this helps. :-)
Cheers!

Comment: Many Thanks guys. I didn't know it could be done without javascript :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
position:fixed;
```

Will do the job. I don't understand why you have to add a script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, no javascript required, check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cardeo/RVrZj/) or here's the CSS

```
#fixed-nav {
 position: fixed;
 background: black;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```